# Randomly change background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm working on a way to change the background pattern of the body on each click of a button.

I got that code so far, but when I click on the button, the background just turns white.
Where is my mistake?

```
var patternImage = ['01','02','03','04'];
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * patternImage.length);

$("#patternSwitcher").click(function(){
    $("body").css("background","url(../images/ + patternImage[randomNumber] + .gif)")
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want:

```
"string" + variable + "string"
```

Not:

```
"string + variable + string"
```

Since variables in JS are not flagged using symbols (such as `$` in PHP), you can't interpolate variables in strings, you have to build them with concatenation.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I changed the concatenation mistake, but it still gives me a white background. I thought it could be because of the path to the images, but i triple-checked and they are named correctly (01.gif, 02.gif, etc) and the path seems right (root/images when the CSS is in root/css). But it still isn't working.

Comment: The CSS is embedded in the HTML document (you are setting the style attribute), not in a separate stylesheet. So unless you are loading /root/css/index.html for example, then you are calculating your path from the wrong place.

Comment: All right, thank you, it's working now! 
I didn't think the style was embedded in the html, making the path different from the one used in the CSS stylesheets. 
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

The string needs to be concatenated:

```
$("body").css("background","url(../images/" + patternImage[randomNumber] + ".gif)")
```